# How do i call a class method using the globals() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to call class methods using the `globals()` function.
I know you can call functions using `globals()` because it works with normal functions.
This is a simple version of the code I have:

```py
class test():
    def func1():
        print("test")

globals()["test.func1"]
```

This also doesn't work:

```py
globals()["test"].globals()["func1"]
```

How do i make it call the function without hardcoding it.

I need the `globals()` function because I don't know in advance which function I am going to call.

Comment: Why is that even inside of a class? Why doesn't it have a `self` parameter? Does it work with a global function?

Comment: "I know you can call functions using ``globals()`` because it works with normal functions." You are jumping to conclusions here. You can *lookup* a function at global scope using ``globals()``, just like you can lookup any other global object that way. ``globals()`` only "cares" whether the target is global, not whether it is a function.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the class, then get it's attributes.

```py
globals()["test"].func1()
```

or

```py
globals()["test"].__dict__['func1']()
```

or

```py
eval("test.func1()")
```

This is also possible:

```py
class A:
    class B:
        class C:
            def func1():
                print("test")

def call_by_dot(string):
    first, *rest = string.split(".")
    obj = globals()[first]
    for i in rest:
        obj = getattr(obj, i)
    return obj

call_by_dot("A.B.C.func1")()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```py
class Test:
    def func1():
        print("test working")



Test.func1()
```

This runs the function `func1()` and produces the result.

output:

```
test working
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class test():
    def func1():
        print ("test")

eval("test.func1()")
```

Comment: I know this works but someone adviced me not to use eval because of security reasons.

Comment: "I don't know in advance which function I am going to call." that's your security risk. Futzing around with global is no better. You are still executing random function in your codebase

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.